# Revision histories of posts show headings being removed and re-added every single revision, even if they aren't changed

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, revisions-list, diff

If a post has heading markup and has been edited, the revision histories' inline and side-by-side views seem to show them all changing on each and every edit, even though they aren't edited at all. (The side-by-side Markdown view isn't affected.)

As an example, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/135361/revisions: in revision 58, Glorfindel added an image. The Markdown diff shows only that part changing:

> [image: Only the relevant line shows as changed]

However, the side-by-side view shows not only that change, but also the headings being removed and re-added:

> [image: Not only the image, but also the headings, are shown as changed (incorrectly)]

This seems to be affecting all posts, not just this post. See also https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/188732/revisions: in this case, as the post has a lot of headers, this bug makes it extremely difficult to zone in on what exactly was changed each edit, as one has to scroll past a lot of headers being (un)changed.

Why is this happening? Can it please be fixed?

Comment: [Here's another relevant revision history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/361567/revisions). In this case, the heading wasn't even edited, but a tag *above* the heading. The heading is highlighted in all (3) revisions with a diff.

Comment: This could be linked to the changes in the rendering that were implemented a few weeks ago. We have more header styles supported (h1 - h6) as well.

Comment: The recent changes to headings could definitely be linked, but that doesn't really explain why they would light up headers on all subsequent and/ or previous revisions as well; if it was a one-time update, I'd assume the light show would happen on only a single revision... it's currently visible in (nearly?) [every single revision for some posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/184109/revisions).

Comment: Another example: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/408437/revisions

Comment: It looks like the issue has been fixed.