# Oneboxed feed post has HTML entities in the title

Tags: bug, chat, title, feed

[This post](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58666905#58666905) from a chat feed has HTML entities in the title:

[image: onebox with " in title]

(note that the quotation marks which are in the question body seem to work just fine)

A [previous post](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/11?m=58637470#58637470) from the same feed does not have the problem:

[image: onebox with quotation mark in title]

A [non-feed onebox of the same post](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58667012#58667012) also doesn't seem to have this problem:

[image: onebox with quotation mark in title]

Maybe this is something to do with [headers being changed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/367622/1017231) and the feed can't understand it? (But then again, maybe not, since that apparently started on the 12th and the feed worked on the 16th)