# Markdown diff shows headers changed, but only body text changed

Tags: bug, markdown, revisions-list, diff

On the revision history for [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/408437/revisions), there are a couple edits which show changes to headers when viewed **Inline**:

[image: incorrect inline diff]

But when switching to the **Side-by-side Markdown** diff, it appears the changes only affect the body text, not the headers:

[image: correct markdown diff]

Comment: This is a dupe of the bug reported here: [Revision histories of posts show headings being removed and re-added every single revision, even if they aren't changed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367394/revision-histories-of-posts-show-headings-being-removed-and-re-added-every-singl) (It’s getting super annoying for posts with many headings, like FAQs…)